# How to use Firebird audit and trace services with Python?

Tags: python, firebird, trace

I'm trying to use audit and trace services with Firebird 2.5, Python 2.7 and FDB 1.4.

This is what I'm doing in Idle:

```
>>> import fdb
>>> svc = fdb.services.connect(password='masterkey', host='localhost')
>>> trace_config = """<database>
enabled true
log_connections true
log_transactions true
log_statement_finish true
time_threshold 0

</database>"""
>>> trace_id = svc.trace_start(trace_config, 'test_trace_2')
>>> svc.readline()
```

After this I'm connecting to database and doing some selects etc, but readline never returns.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: At first glance I'd say it should be ok, is there anything in the firebird log?

Comment: Nothing in log, except few disconnects because if restarting Python shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that there's 64kb buffer for output. There's a way to get output directly, from FDB author Pavel Cisar:

```
while 1:
    try:
       line = svc._QS(fdb.ibase.isc_info_svc_line)
    except fdb.OperationalError:
       # It is routine for actions such as RESTORE to raise an
       # exception at the end of their output.  We ignore any such
       # exception and assume that it was expected, which is somewhat
       # risky.  For example, suppose the network connection is broken
       # while the client is receiving the action&#39;s output...
       break
    if not line: # we reached the end of output
       break
    print line
```